# starting a server using pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I can run a server on local using command - `node dist/index.js start --fairos`
but I am trying to run a server on production using `pm2` but getting this on logs-

pm2 command - `pm2 start dist/index.js --name myapp -- --fairos`

logs-

```
0|myapp    | Not a valid group or command: --fairos
```

any ideas how can I run this on production?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using npm? A startscript section in package.json?

Comment: Thanks @ztom for your response-
you can check-
`"scripts": {
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --progress --env mode=production",
    "start": "webpack --progress",
    "test": "jest --verbose --config=jest.config.ts -i",
    "types:check": "tsc --project tsconfig.test.json",
    "lint": "eslint --fix \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\" && prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "lint:check": "eslint \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\" && prettier --check \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "depcheck": "depcheck ."
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you exactly what your problem is. I guess it is the path to node.js bin that is missing.

This is how it works for me: Create a script entry (i.e. pm2starter)

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --progress",
    "pm2starter": "pm2 start npm --name \"myapp\" -- run start --fairos"
},
```

Then you can start the app from wherever you want:

`npm run pm2starter --prefix /var/www/<path-to-project>`